# Which nation forced Romans to change their armor?

Tags: ancient-rome

I remember reading somewhere that at a certain point in history thanks to archaic steel an enemy of Rome had swords that could cut through armor with ease causing a large change in Roman military but I forgot which country it was.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? Have you looked on [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=XZgNWoPfCYvYgAbHrby4Cw&q=roman+armour&oq=roman+armour) or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_military_personal_equipment#Torso_armour)? You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: What has preliminary research revealed?

Comment: Not much mainly because i don't know what to search exactly as i forgot the name of the country that forced romans to make the changes.

Comment: Some more information would be helpful. What time period are we discussing? "Rome" lasted quite a while. That said, are you perhaps referring to the Dacians? Off the top of my head I think of Trajan's wars in Dacia, which inspired them to reinforce their helmets and wear manica (armor which extends down their right arm) as well as wear greaves (at least so we surmise from limited depictions of that campaign).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may be thinking of [Dacia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dacia) and their [Falx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falx#Dacian_falx).

[image]

The falx may have defeated Roman armor more by form and use(as a two-handed weapon) then by superior steel however.

The book [The Dacian Threat](https://books.google.com/books?id=swDMiX4_9GIC&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=Michael%20Schmitz%20The%20Dacian%20threat,&source=bl&ots=ViLHRkg071&sig=Dj2lBZAmqDXil3UcvnGD17KJd2o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7wPn-qcPXAhUjsVQKHTxwCO0Q6AEIOTAE#v=onepage&q&f=false), by  Michael Schmitz discusses this on page 39. Some of the upgrades caused included:

- issued the *[manica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manica_(armguard))* to legionnaires fighting the Dacians
- modified forms of the *[lorica squamata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorica_squamata)* and *[lorica hamata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorica_hamata)*
- reinforced helmets

Comment: Did you know *Thank you* is too short to be a comment...

Comment: @justCal And with good reason, since [comments like that are discouraged](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). If you appreciate a question, an answer, or a comment, but have nothing meaningful to add to it - an upvote is enough.

Comment: If I remember well Gallic Tribes also had superior armors and weapons. But I'm not sure they produced so many changes in Roman military tactics and/or equipment.

Comment: @xrorox: TheGallic tribes induced the *Marian reforms* following the [Battle of Noreia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Noreia).